# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'Product'. in distinct List

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql

I'm using Linq to Sql.

Here's the data in my database

```
Cat 20 is Stationery
Cat 30 is Computer Items
Cat 40 is Toiletry

**Id CatId ProductName**
1   20     Pencil
1   20     Pen
1   30     Compact Disc
1   30     USB
1   30     Hard drive
1   40     Toothpaste
1   40     Toothbrush
```

I retrieve all my products as below

```
List<Product> c = myContext.GetProducts(activeStatus).ToList();
```

This works when i bind the data to my datasource (Gridview, Repeater etc on my ASPX web forms page).

I now want to get all distinct products by category so i create the below code

```
List<Product> cats = c.Select(cat => cat.CatId).Distinct().ToList();
```

But this produces the error

> "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'Product'

Where am i going wrong?

Comment: Your select statement returns a collection of category id's, not a collection of products. Can you explain why you expected the statement to return a list of products?

Comment: I thought i was getting products with distinct ids.... I assume MoreLinq is the way to go.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic projects `distinct CatId` and converting that to a `List`. This is why you can't capture it as `List<Product>` (as there no implicit conversion exists between `int` and custom `Product`).

You have few options here to retrieve distinct `Products` if that what you aiming for:

a. Get all distinct `CatId` and iterate over the `Product` collection to create a subset.

```
//get all distinct CatIds    
var catIds = c.Select(cat => cat.CatId).Distinct().ToList();
//retrieve products that belongs to catids
var products = c.Where(p => catIds.Contains(p.CatId))
```

b. If you prefer, a further approach would be to implement `IEqualityComparer<T> interface` [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.iequalitycomparer-1?view=netframework-4.8) and a sample implementation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinct?view=netframework-4.8). This approach provides further flexibility for deciding uniqueness. For example, as of now you only have `CatId` field to see what is distinct. But if you have more fields other than `CatId` then this implementation will scale well than choice provided under Srl a.

c. Final option is to extract distinct with help of `GroupBy`. Here we are grouping `Products` by `CatId` and then picking the `first` one in the list.

```
IEnumerable<Product> distinctProducts = c.GroupBy(pro => pro.CatId)
                                                 .Select(f => f.First());
```

As with any solution, see what works and apt in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Your desired result from Distinct CatId which is currently not support by default Linq. I suggest using DistinctBy in [MoreLinq](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ)

```
var query = c.DistinctBy(p => p.CatId).ToList();
```

Answer (score -2):

You should to create class like this

```
public static class ConverterLocal
    {
        public static ReturnType GetProduct(this int id)
        {
            //Here your statement
            return ReturnType;
        }
    }
```

For use this

```
30.GetProduct()
```